# ResponseStream and RequestStream Never Continue if Called From Separate Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core, grpc

The Chat sample (.Net Framework 4.x) includes code that interleaves reads and writes to the same `AsyncDuplexStreamingCall`. I changed the .Net Core Greeter example to include a streaming RPC:

```proto
service GreetingService {
    rpc Greeting(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
    rpc StreamGreeting(stream HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloResponse);
}
```

I then basically copied the echo implementation for the server:

```cs
public override async Task StreamGreeting(/* ... */)
{
    while (await requestStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
    {
        var request = requestStream.Current;
        Console.WriteLine($"Stream Message: {request.Name}");
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(new HelloResponse { Greeting = "Stream Hello " + request.Name });
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Stream completed.");
}
```

Finally, I attempted to read and write to this stream from separate threads:

```cs
var callResult = client.StreamGreeting(new CallOptions());
// Or: Task.Run
new Thread(async () =>
{
    await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
    await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
    await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
    await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
    await callResult.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
}).Start();
new Thread(async () =>
{
    while (await callResult.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(callResult.ResponseStream.Current.Greeting);
    }
}).Start();
```

The first call to `WriteAsync` succeeds (the server logs that it received the message), but the second one never returns/continues. `ResponseStream.MoveNext` never returns/continues. Running either on the main task/thread doesn't resolve the issue. Running both on the main task/thread does work, including all forms of interleaved calls.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a limitation?

Comment: Using RequestStream and ResponseStream from two separate threads should really work just fine, and I don't immediately see a problem in your code. What gRPC version are you using? Can your run the example in a debugger and tell where it got stuck?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue, for me the test finished without any problems with both Task and Thread (I used MathService.DivMany from Grpc.Examples project under src/csharp and tested on the latest upstream/master code).

Comment: Please also note that there's a potential problem with your code: new Thread(async () => {  await Task.Delay(100000); }), the newly created thread will immediately finish (it won't wait for the async lambda). Could that be what's causing the issue in your example? See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/08/potential-pitfalls-to-avoid-when-passing-around-async-lambdas/

Comment: @JanTattermusch as this is just me messing about, I had a Console.Readline following the snippet. I will have a look at the samples, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the result you describe, but only when including line `channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait()` from the `GreeterClient` example immediately after issuing the processing threads.

This then causes an `InvalidOperationException` as the client stub is shut down while the streaming call is in progress.

To ensure that all four calls are processed on the server, you'd need to wait for all streaming requests and responses to be done before shutting down:

```
  var callResult = client.StreamGreeting(new CallOptions());
  Task.WhenAll(new[]
  {
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
      await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
      await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
      await callResult.RequestStream.WriteAsync(request);
      await callResult.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
    }),
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      while (await callResult.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
      {
        Console.WriteLine(callResult.ResponseStream.Current.Greeting);
      }
    })
  }).Wait();
```